# Building a trackless, sliding projector mount

Tags: mounting, installation, cabinets, home-automation, projector

I have a neat little motorized projector screen that disappears into the ceiling space when I'm not using it. It's mounted 50 cm from the wall, so it drops down just in front of my 47cm deep console + 45cm deep subwoofer.

At the moment, I have to drag my UST projector out and position it in the right spot when I want to use this screen. I want to automate this (absolutely ridiculous, first world problem) and would love some feedback from other tinkerers.

The plan is built around 200% extension drawer slides. These have a closed length of 450mm and a full extension of 1350mm; so short enough to disappear under the console when not in use, but more than enough stroke to put my projector at the desired distance (1.2m from the wall). I'll mount these slides under the console with a little tray; the projector will sit on that; I'll wire up a telescoping linear actuator (this could be as simple as an old car antenna assembly) and boom, needless automation.

The gotcha here is that a pair of 450mm 200% extension slides cost about three hundred bucks. I could just tack two 100% sets together; I could try and get away with the linear actuator only and a metal tray that just slides along the carpet unsupported; but the positioning needs to be pretty precise and I just feel like proper, single piece slides are the only way I'm going to get that. Am I missing an easier way? I obviously can't get away with permanent tracks fixed to the floor in front of the cabinet, the appeal of the current setup is that it all disappears and the living room looks normal when you throw a switch.

In before "the easier way is to just spend five seconds doing it manually" - I've been in a combination of COVID and toddler lockdown for the last two years and have become increasingly dependent on stupid DIY projects to keep me sane.

Comment: I think I follow what you're attempting to do, but a drawing (doesn't have to be precise or to scale) would most certainly help. Also, home automation is all about solving non-existent, 1st world problems with needless complexity*, so quit apologizing. ;) (*Except in the case of those for whom the simple act of flipping a light switch is extremely difficult or impossible...)

Comment: To my own defense of flipping on a light switch, it's handy to automate my basement steps light in case I have my hands full and forgot to flip it on!

Comment: Using 100% extensions only puts you 17" closer, no? Is that a big deal?

Comment: I would strongly suggest something (needlessly automated and hidden/disguised when not in use, if you like) mounted on the ceiling for the projector. Particularly with toddler. The odds of the floor / near floor being clear seem far lower, and it keeps the fragile stuff up out of harm's way. I think you are being distracted by "replicating where you put it now" rather than "what's the best way to perma-mount it."

Comment: Ultra Short Throw (UST) - the kind you put in front of you on the coffee table... not a real projector that belongs mounted to the ceiling. - But yes, mount it to the ceiling, presuming it has a vertical flip and one hell of a keystone.

Answer (score 1):

First, confirm it will work. Then use the 600 dollar slides. Your new setup will be sliding open and closed many times, carrying expensive equipment. Plus you know you have a solid working platform if you upgrade the equipment in the future. To sit back and push a button for entertainment puts you in the same realm as Matt Helm. He had a station wagon with a bed in the back and push-button everything.

Comment: *carrying expensive equipment* that shouldn't be jostled around while it's still hot.